# Vehicles' or Vehicles are spinning out of control

Tags: apostrophe

Is it Vehicles or Vehicles' were spinning out of control. I have checked the rule and I though the apostrophe is for ownership and i don't believe there is direct ownership in this line but my friend says that you put the apostrophe.

Comment: `Vehicles'` is the possessive for multiple vehicles, as you suggest.  It should be `Vehicles`.

Comment: What is your friend's reason for needing the apostrophe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is sometimes a need for an apostrophe, but that is usually when the word in question (e.g., vehicles) precedes a gerund. Even then, the apostrophe is not necessarily needed. For example, the following sentence does not need an apostrophe:

> The vehicles speeding past the sign were too many to count.

On the other hand, the following sentence would need an apostrophe:

> The vehicles' speeding was documented by a cop with a speed gun.

The former sentence has nothing to do with ownership, or possession, but simply the kind of vehicles they were; namely, *speeding* vehicles (adjective, noun). You could substitute bicycles, runners, birds--or whatever, for vehicles.

The latter sentence does have to do with ownership, or possession, in that the speeding, in a sense, belonged to the vehicles. It was their speeding, so to speak, which was caught by the cop with the speed gun.

With the ground rules I've laid out for you, is an apostrophe needed or not in the following sentences?

> I was impressed by Jim's/Jim speeding.
>
> The photographer captured two lions'/lions pouncing on the prey.
>
> The girl's/girl smiling at me was the one I chose as my date for the dance.
>
> If you ever see Sally's/Sally walking down Main Street, please let me know.
>
> Paul's/Paul winning that many medals made me a bit envious.

[Answers: yes, no, no, no, yes]

Hint: If you're not sure an apostrophe is needed, simply ask the question (for example), "Whose speeding impressed you?" (my sentence 1), or "Whose winning made you envious?" (my sentence 5). If the possessive "whose" is an appropriate answer, then an apostrophe would in order. If not, then not.